# Using source control principles for managing a map, set, dictionary, or relation table?

Tags: version-control, dictionary

In the process of managing something like a dictionary (a mapping between words and definitions) you would need to add and remove words and update definitions, and make any changes as needed.  It would be nice to track such changes similar to how source code changes are tracked with version control software. However, there are a few differences between a map and source files. The biggest difference I can think of is that order does not matter in the map, you can order your words and definitions as you like (although a default ordering could be assumed).

Is there any existing software well suited to tracking changes in a dictionary (or a map data-structure, or a relational database)?  I would like a way to be able to answer questions like "When was this word added?" or "When did the definition for this word change?" or even "What words were previously in the dictionary which have since been removed completely?"

Answer (score 0):

I think, you use almost any SCM for your task. Most of VCS ("Version Control System", note: nothing said about source code) have "blame" or equivalent command to detect history on per-string basis. String-order **is** important for most usual situation in development, thus - you can not disable track these changes of code, but you can use differ-merger, which **detect an show** such changes (outside used SCM) - I know about this feature in CompareIT, f.e.

For me reasonably good VCS for your task seems Git (with it grep, git-blame, annotate) and Mercurial (with revsets, blame, grep)

Comment: @Buttons840 I couldn't find *fast answer* only on last your question

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you need VCS for that purpose. If you say that you use relational database for mapping storage, then you should add corresponding fields into the mapping structure. For example, if you have two tables with many-to-many relation, it will have 3 tables: `T1`, `T2` and `T1_to_T2` with following relations: `T1` <- `T1_to_T2` -> `T2`. What you need is just add such fields as `CreateDate` and `UpdateDate` to the mapping table `T1_to_T2`. It will allow to answer with the help of SQL on all of those questions:

- When was the mapping record added?
- When did the mapping record change?
- What records do not have mapping and when did that happen?